# I have used so many "if" and I would like to know if I can substitute some by "case"

Tags: pascal, freepascal

I have this code:

```
program Coordenadas;
var
    x,z : integer;
begin
  writeln('Ingresa la coordenada en X.');
  readln(x);
  writeln('Ingresa la coordenada en Z.');
  readln(z);
  if (x=0) and (z=0) then 
    writeLn('La coordenada 0 0 es el centro del mundo.')
  else if abs(x)=abs(z) then
    if x>0 then 
      if z>0 then 
        writeln(x,' ', z,' se ubica en el Sureste') 
      else 
        writeln(x,' ', z,' se ubica en el Noreste')
    else if z>0 then 
      writeln(x,' ', z,' se ubica en el Suroeste') 
    else 
      writeln(x,' ', z,' se ubica en el Noroeste')
  else if abs(x)>abs(z) then
    if x>0 then 
      writeln(x,' ', z, ' se ubica en el Este.')
    else 
      writeln(x,' ', z, ' se ubica en el Oeste.')
    else if z>0 then 
      writeln(x,' ', z, ' se ubica en el Sur.')
    else 
      writeln(x,' ', z, ' se ubica en el Norte.')
end.
```

It seems too repetitive. Can I shorten it, perhaps by using `case`?

Comment: You can't use a "case of" because that works with integers compared to fixed integer values. You could use some begin/end to simplify this convoluted tests, but that is all you can do, the structure of the tests is quite univoque.

Comment: Sometimes you can linearize all possibilities with e.g. something like sign(x)+factor*sign(z) , but there are multiple checks here using both abs() and not, so that will be difficult.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do i use multiple statements to one case statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27536579/how-do-i-use-multiple-statements-to-one-case-statement)

Answer (score 1):

Your program has nine distinct outcomes. Without skipping newlines, there's only so concise you can make it. At the risk of actually *increasing* repetition, you can reduce indentation, which may make it easier to follow the logic of the program.

```
if A then
  if B then
    V
  else
    W
else if C then
  if D then
    X
  else
    Y
else
  Z
```

Is equivalent to:

```
if A and B then
  V
else if A then
  W
else if C and D then
  X
else if C then
  Y
else
  Z
```

Answer (score 0):

> […] I would like to know how to shorten it maybe with "case" […]

Pascal – as defined by ISO standards 7185 “Standard Pascal” and 10206 “Extended Pascal” – has the data type `integer`.
An `integer` value is an integral value in the range `−maxInt‥+maxInt`.
Thus

```pascal
case myIntegerExpression of
    −maxInt‥+maxInt:
        writeLn('Ya1k');
end;
```

will *always* print `Ya1k` *regardless* of the specific value of `myIntegerExpression` (presuming it is defined).
In your case you could write multiple non-overlapping `case`-labels, `−maxInt‥0` to match non-positive `integer` values and `1‥maxInt`.

However, this will not necessarily reduce your code’s length, yet it *may* become more *readable*.
Remember, *you* write code for *humans*.
Humans should be able to read *and understand* your code.
It is a minor, (almost) *negligible* issue that a machine, a computer, needs to be able to process your code, too.

---

> […] I tested it and already works, but I feel it is too repetitive. […]

Generally speaking, you use *routines* for repetitive tasks.
In your particular case it is remarkable that you do not use `write` (*without* the `Ln` in the end).
You could print a common prefix with `write` and write the final word(s) with `writeLn`.

---

> ```pascal
> writeln('Ingresa la coordenada en X.');
> readln(x);
> writeln('Ingresa la coordenada en Z.');
> readln(z);
> ```

`read`/`readLn` accept *multiple* variables.
You could merge both prompts into one prompt.
It is *advisable* that your prompt message *tells* the user *all* details.
In particular your prompt should *emphasize* that only `integer` values (no `real` values) are valid since *discrete* coordinate systems are somewhat less common (= less expected).
Again, write your programs *for* humans.

---

In Pascal instead of writing

> ```pascal
> if (x=0) and (z=0) then
> ```

it is (incidentally more concise and) *more idiomatic* to write

```pascal
if [x, z] = [0] then
```

At least *mathematicians* use sets a lot.
(Keep in mind that Pascal, however, supports only sets with an ordinal base type.)